# Sqlite database location via javascript in the context of Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sqlite

[PRE-NOTE: I am targeting only chrome/android default browser]

Hi,

I am currently using js statement `var db = openDatabase ('db_name', '', 'db_desc', 2*1024*1024);` to open sqlite database and run my transactions.

I find the sqlite file located at `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases\file__0\5`.

Can I somehow indicate the location to my sqlite database file explicitly (absolute path or something as mentioned [here](http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/articles/10-xul/24-accessing-directories-and-location-in-xul-by-javascript.html))?

I see this can be done for [XUL applications](http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/articles/10-xul/25-sqlite-api-for-xul-application-using-javascript.html) e.g. `var con = new SQLite("test.sqlite",{location:'Desk'});`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't specify a SQLite database manually.

The web sql database support in Chrome sandboxes the database to a specific origin (schema, host, port combination), and handles the database's creation and permissions transparently. It's quite different than the SQLite API in XUL, but has the advantage of being useful inside everyday web applications that don't require permissions to access arbitrary bits of the local computer's filesystem.

Comment: I might go little away from my previous question and also commenting with less knowledge.

When you talk about "advantage of not requiring permissions", isn't there a problem if you visit N number of websites each trying to openDatabase with M MB size such that (MxN) MB hits limit (hypothetical may be). Or will chrome delete some of the database files to keep the size limit intact?

This was my concern and somehow wanted to keep the location elsewhere (Note: This is targeting specific desktop clients only if its question about security)

Comment: Engineers are in the process of implementing a quota system for all forms of locally stored data that will let users decide how much space websites in general should have to work with. At the moment, if you run out of space, database creation will simply fail. Soon, you'll be able to determine that the failure is due to hitting the quota, and message the user appropriately. See http://crbug.com/61676 for implementation details/status.