# Open external sqlite3 database in Javascript

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite

I have an sqlite3 database called mydb.db. It is an external file. Is it possible to open up this DB in javascript?

I tried the following code but this results in mydb.db being created wherever chrome creates it's DB's, so it clearly isn't loading mine from file.

```
try {
    if (!window.openDatabase) {
        alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
    } else {
        var Name = 'mydb.db';
        var version = '1.0'; //1.0
        var displayName = 'TEST';
        var maxSize = 100000; //  bytes
        database = openDatabase(Name, version, displayName, maxSize);
    }
} catch(e) {
    ...
}
```

Thanks,
J

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041083/sqlite-database-location-via-javascript-in-the-context-of-chrome-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. (At least not by this means.)

Allowing arbitrary file/database access would be a security vulnerability. Imagine a file "C:\My Documents\My Bank Data\transactions.sqlite" ..

(Actually, I'd expect browsers to sandbox/abstract the db "name" away from the physical file as a sane, but implementation-specific, strategy.)

Comment: I thought this would be the case. Thanks.